# Visual Studio C++ project - Can't find std lib

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, resharper, resharper-c++

Sorry for the dumb question but I'm new to using Visual Studio for C++ ...

I have a custom C++ project in Visual Studio 2013 (it's an example project for developing Reason rack extensions) and everything works but I also have ReSharper installed and it shows me a lot of errors in the code pointing out that std files and types aren't found (e.g.  `stddef.h`, `cmath`, `NULL`, among others).

How do I tell the project (or ReSharper?) to find them?

Comment: Can you post some code or better example? Also which include directories you have in your project as well which platform toolset do you use? 32 vs 64b? 2013 pro or 2013 express? There is really a lot of possibilities.

Comment: Posting any code is a bit difficult as it's a whole project. I doubt that will help much. Include Directories in the project properties are set to: $(VC_IncludePath)
$(WindowsSDK_IncludePath) and this is in VS 2013 Pro 64bit. The project does compile as it's built via the RE SDK's build scripts (afaik) but since the error markers tell that the std classes are'nt found I suppose it's an issue that Intellisense has?

Comment: Could you post the `*.vcxproj` file to a gist or something, so the ReSharper C++ dev team can take a look, please?

Comment: @citizenmatt Sure, if it helps ... https://gist.github.com/hexagonstar/dc85e7add3456665dfc1